# Updating pandas dataframe values assigns Nan

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: Col1, Col2 and Col3.

Toy example

```
d = {'Col1':['hello','k','hello','we','r'],
     'Col2':[10,20,30,40,50],
     'Col3':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Which gets:

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
0  hello    10     1
1      k    20     2
2  hello    30     3
3     we    40     4
4      r    50     5
```

I am selecting the values of `Col2` such that the value in `Col1` is 'hello'

```
my_values = df.loc[df['Col1']=='hello']['Col2']
```

this returns me a Series where I can see the values of `Col2` as well as the index.

```
0    10
2    30
Name: Col2, dtype: int64
```

Now suppose I want to assign this values to a Col3.

I only want to replace those values(index 0 and 2), keeping the other values in Col3 unmodified

I tried:

```
df['Col3'] = my_values
```

But this assigns `Nan` to the other values (the ones where Col1 is not hello)

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
0  hello    10    10
1      k    20   NaN
2  hello    30    30
3     we    40   NaN
4      r    50   NaN
```

How can I update certain values in Col3 leaving the others untouched?

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3
0  hello    10    10
1      k    20   2
2  hello    30    30
3     we    40   4
4      r    50   5
```

So, in short:

Having my_values I want to put them in Col3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just base on `np.where`

```
df['Col3']=np.where(df['Col1'] == 'hello',df.Col2,df.Col3)
```

If base on your myvalue

```
df.loc[my_values.index,'col3']=my_values
```

Or you can just do `update`

```
df['Col3'].update(my_values)
```

Comment: Ok, yes. **Update** is exactly what I'm looking for! It takes a Series and updates a column only with it's values.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki  hah, glad I can help